# Reference book for hydraulic systems design

Tags: fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, pressure, hydraulics, systems-engineering

I'm looking for a good reference book on the topic of fluid dynamics/hydraulics systems engineering.

I'd like a reference for simlpe/estimate calculations on things like major losses (pipes), minor losses (bends, orifices, expansions, contractions, etc). The media that I most frequently work with are water, glycol, hydrogen and air.

I know that CFD and exact value calculations can be quite cumbersome in fluid dynamics, and that is why I am looking for an engineering reference book for estimate calculations that can help simplify the calculations when I need to make system design estimates (>100 different calculations).

Please let me know if you have any suggestions!

Comment: Mannesman Rexroth Sigma do a series of 6 - notxsure if they are for salevto general public but you can ask - superb books

Comment: Crane Technical Paper 410 will probably work well for what you're looking for.

Comment: Handbook of Hydraulic Resistance by I.E. Idelchik. This is a reference manual of loss coefficients/discharge coefficients for numerous types of flow geometries. Most complete resource I have found thus far.